# Рамка в окне уведомления QMessageBox

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, qss, qmessagebox

Нужно как-то сделать рамку в информационном окне. Ещё плохо ознакомлен с *PyQT5* и не знаю как это реализовать.

Нужно чтобы вокруг текста "hallo" была рамка, желательно цветная.

[image: Нужно чтобы вокруг текста "hallo" была рамка, желательно цветная]

Вот код, как я создаю информационное окно.

```
from PyQt5.Qt import *

class App(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = ''
        self.left = 840
        self.top = 460
        self.width = 320
        self.height = 200
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)


        l = "hallo"

        buttonReply = QMessageBox.information(self, 'СООБЩЕНИЕ', l, QMessageBox.Ok)

        self.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMessageBox


app = QApplication(sys.argv)

app.setStyleSheet('''
QDialogButtonBox {
    dialogbuttonbox-buttons-have-icons: 1;
    dialog-ok-icon: url(./images/Ok.png);
}
#qt_msgbox_label {
    color: white;
    background: #3B0000;
    border: 2px solid #FF95C5;
    border-radius: 3px;
    min-height: 27px;
    min-width: 80px;
}
#qt_msgboxex_icon_label {
    background: #BE0000;
}
QMessageBox {
    background: black;
    messagebox-information-icon: url(./images/Close.png);
}
QMessageBox QPushButton {
    padding: 2px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: white;
}
QMessageBox QPushButton:hover {
    background: darkCyan;
}
''')

QMessageBox.information(
    None, 
    "information", 
    "<p style='color: white; text-align: center;'>Hello World</p>",
    QMessageBox.Ok 
)
                     
sys.exit()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]